# R Profiler Line Instances

Tags: r, profiler

I'm relatively new to R so please forgive me if this seems elementary.

I've been using an R profiler as of late and I find it rather useful for seeing how much time was spent on each particular line.

Per Richard Scriven's request: I'm currently using the `Rprof` profiling function. Hope that helps.

That being said, in the process that I am running I'm calling several helper functions regularly and it comes as no surprise that they eat a large chunk of the processing time.

Is there a setting, or another profiling option, which will allow me to not only see the amount of time spent per line, BUT the total number of instances that each line was called?

This may help me 'discount' the apparent 'slowness' of some lines of code on the basis of how frequently they were called.

Thanks,

James

Comment: Please be specific as to what you mean by *R profiler*.  There are a few different code profiling functions.

Comment: Added some further information into the question, not sure if it is useful :p

Comment: The Rprof I've used generates a file of stack samples. Then I just pick a few random samples, like 10, out of that and examine them. Suppose line L has X% inclusive time. That means it is on the stack X% of the time, so I will see it on about X% of the stack samples. The measurements I get this way are crude, but that doesn't matter. Nothing gives a better insight into how and why the time is spent.